# DAX - Highest amount for a product comparing to previous day

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have data like in column Date, Product and Amount. I am looking for DAX code to generate column NewHigh (max Amount comparing to previous Date) If it is highest then Yes in column

[image]

would like to have a column showing yes or no
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a  **`Measure`** like this

```
Measure = 
VAR _maxDate =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR _prod =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Product] )
VAR _Amt =
    SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Product] = _prod && 'Table'[Date] < _maxDate )
    )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingAmt =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] = _immediatelyPrecedingDate
                && 'Table'[Product] = _prod
        )
    )
VAR _comp =
    IF ( _immediatelyPrecedingAmt < _Amt, "Yes", "No" )
RETURN
    _comp
```

or a **`Calculated Column`** like this

```
Column = 
VAR _maxDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ) )
VAR _prod =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Product] ) )
VAR _Amt =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ) )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[Product] = _prod && 'Table'[Date] < _maxDate )
    )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingAmt =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Amount] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[Date] = _immediatelyPrecedingDate
                && 'Table'[Product] = _prod
        )
    )
VAR _comp =
    IF ( _immediatelyPrecedingAmt < _Amt, "Yes", "No" )
RETURN
    _comp
```

Comment: it is working for the previous day however, the value for earlier day has not been account for. 
Date Product  Amount
2021/12/17 C 26
2021/12/18 C 9
2021/12/19 C 25
2021/12/20 C 33

on 2021/12/19 the value is small than the value on 2021/12/19 but is showing up as yes in the measure. Is there a workaround to this? thanks

Comment: I have slightly edited the calculation. Please try out.